# Disable related videos bar in iframe

Tags: youtube-api

I know that Youtube changed the ability to remove related videos (it'll show public videos in that channel now if you set `rel=0`. But i noticed some websites not having the related video, but when i try it with the iframe on my website, it has the related videos.

Is there any API or youtube request needed to remove the related videos?

Answer (score 0):

There aren't official youtube api that accomplish this after changes you cited (ref: https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#release_notes_08_23_2018).

Only with workarounds you can "disable", or better "not show" related videos.

There are some snippets on the web, look those!

ps: example this https://www.maxlaumeister.com/blog/hide-related-videos-in-youtube-embeds/ (a platform's plugin or vanilla code)